# .NET как отловаить внезапный crash программы

Tags: .net, vb.net

Имеется такая проблема, как внезапные завершение программы на некоторыx компьютераx, без ошибки или еще чего либо. К сожалению debug-тестами, так и не удалось выяснить чем же является данная проблема.

Интересует сообственно метод, которым можно было бы отлавливать внезапные завершения/crash программы.
Желательно с log-файлом, с записью разной информации.

Comment: У вас есть исходники программы?

Comment: https://metanit.com/visualbasic/tutorial/3.14.php

Comment: @AzizUmarov программу писал сам, так что да, исходники есть. Предоставить не могу, ибо слишком много кода)
Try..Catch.. из вашей ссылке не поможет, ибо .NET покажет ошибку, если ее не сможет обработать. В данном же случае, это просто странные и внезапные вылеты.

Comment: Сколько программировал всегда отлавливал ошибки и внезапных не было. Я так понимаю у Вас многопоточное приложение и рушится дочерний поток который тянет ко дну всесь процесс.

Comment: @AzizUmarov не совсем так, мутипоточность есть и то, для загрузок данных, но в момент вылета, он ничего не делает. Я бы даже сказал, вылет похож на выполнение этой команды  - Environment.FailFast. Сначала думал, может происходит где-то утечка памяти, но результат показал отрицательный результат

Answer (score 1):

Если это Framework 4.x Windows Form App то в свойствах проекта, вкладка Application есть кнопка View Application Events, и собственно событие Me.UnhandledException, которое вызывается если исключение не было обработано явно.

Если это Core 5 или 6 WPF то можно повесить обработчик, например:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

Собственно там можно реализовывать обработку внезапностей или общую логику.

Например:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Write(Log.Level.Info, $"DataSource: {Properties.Settings.Default.MsSqlDataSource}");
        DataContext = new InstallerViewModel();
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = (Exception) e.ExceptionObject;
        Log.Write(Log.Level.Error, ex.Message);
        Log.Close();
    }
}
```